# Can ESP32 flash its own flash from SD card?

Tags: esp32

So, I was wondering is it possible to create some sort of "bootloader" for ESP32 programs, which would load said programs from SD card?

I know I can't do it on the flight, so my idea was: Create a sort of OTA without internet and second partition, because my particular usecase will need every bit of memory it can get, so **splitting it up is not really a option**.

Right now I see two problems:

1. I need to terminate everything once I start loading the program (mainly FreeRTOS, so there isn't any potential interrupt)
2. I need to fit everything into IRAM and leave enough space for the rest of the application.
   This will need a total rewrite of esp-idf functions since most of them are not in the IRAM.

Comment: what else would write OTA update to flash if not the esp32. it doesn't matter what is the source of the new binary. it just needs to be written into the right partition and then activated

Answer (score 1):

I used the partition-table and OTA to flash from SD while maintaining (most) of the Flash memory:
mapping FACTORY and OTA0 to the same address & a small OTA1 partition does the trick.

When my application in the FACTORY/OTA0 detects a firmware.bin file on the SD-card, it reboots into OTA1. The program stored in OTA1 updates OTA0, renames the firmware.bin file and initiates a reboot from OTA0.
By this I loose very litte Flash memory for the SD-Boot capability and can still flash via USB using FACTORY partition.

I wrote the code some years ago, so I would have to find it again... and re-understand it. Maybe a job for the next weeks.

Greetings
GvTT

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No need for IRAM, you can run your application from Flash and write to same Flash at the same time without any problems. Espressif has provided an API for doing just what you want: [Over The Air Updates (OTA)](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/ota.html). You have to create separate partitions for the currently running firmware and the "fresh" one (as described in the document). Then you just read your new firmware image's data from the SD card and feed it to the API's `esp_ota_write...()` function.

Comment: It's worth noting the downside of OTA halving of the max usable image size, since it splits the flash into two partitions.

Comment: Yes, OTA would work, but I need the whole flash, I can't really afford to split it up...

Comment: The alternative to Espressif's OTA is to build it yourself from scratch - which is not trivial. It's up to you to decide, but you'll be looking at a few orders of magnitude more work than adopting the ready-made solution. Perhaps you can use a module with 8 or 16 MiB of Flash?

Comment: @haberturdeur, you created a custom partitioning which uses the whole flash? the default partitioning has a partition for second copy of the application

Comment: Essentially yes. I haven't done it yet, because I am still doing the low level stuff, but I have done it multiple times in other projects...